# Find a kernel in a directed graph.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

It's a question from a sample exam I'm trying to solve but with no success yet.

> Let $G(V, E)$ be a directed graph. set $A \subseteq V$ is a ***kernel*** if:
>
> i. $\forall u,v\in A \implies (u, v), (v, u) \notin E $ (no edge between two vetex in $A$)
>
> ii. $\forall v \in V $ \ $A, \space \space  \exists a\in A$ such that $(a, v) \in E$.
>
> In other words, there's an edge between vertex in A and vertex outside of A.
>
> ---
>
> Suggest an algorithms that finds a kernel in a cycle-less directed graph.
>
> Rqueired runtime: $O(V + E)$.

Can you please give me some hints to find this problem? Thanks in adnvace.

Comment: I think using a depth first search in an appropriate way solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

1. Let $A'$ be all vertices with in-degree 0, and let $A''$ be their neighbors
2. Add vertices in $A'$ to $A$
3. Add vertices in $A''$ to $V \setminus A$
4. Remove $A' \cup A''$ from $G$ and repeat steps 1-3 until the graph is empty

**Correctness:** Since there are no edges between vertices with in-degree 0, property (i) holds for $A'$. As all neighbors of $A'$ are removed in step 4, no edges exist between vertices that are in $A'$ in different iterations.

Every vertex $v \in V \setminus A$ is in $A''$ in some iteration. In the same iteration, there is, by definition of $A''$, a vertex $a \in A'$ with $(a,v) \in E$.

**Runtime:** The algorithm can be implemented by running a breadth-first type search starting from the set of vertices with in-degree 0. In step 4, it is easy to find the in-degree 0 vertices of the next iteration (they have to be neighbors of vertices in $A''$).

Comment: In step 1, should it be vertices with minimum in-degree instead of 0 in-degree? Since it is possible to construct a graph with all vertices having non-zero in-degree.